# How to read a third party application's chat / log from the computer memory

Tags: c++, memory

Imagine a 3rd party application (game) like farmville or something where things occur and it spits out text like "your farm needs XYZ". Since it's on my computer, I know the text must be on my computer memory somewhere. I want to be able to access that text information from my computer memory so that I can use it as input for a script.

How do I go about searching my computer memory for that text in real time?

Comment: How about making a tunnel device and listening in on all your network traffic? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a very good tutorial on how to do this but it was taken off the net. Fortunately the [Wayback Machine has a archived copy of it](http://web.archive.org/web/20110613060052/www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-poker-bot).

[Here is a link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110903010711/www.codingthewheel.com/tags/poker%20bot) to the tags page that should get you to the other parts of the article, I believe there are 8 parts, but there are other relevant pages on that tag page too.